# Reading a .asm file in a compiler via a read function

Tags: c

I'm trying to write a program that will be able to read an .asm file, in c.

```
#include  <stdio.h>

int preprocess_get_line(char label[], char instruction[], FILE* fp);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    /* Open file and check success */
    char *filename = "helloworld.asm";
    if (argc >1)
    {
        filename = argv[1];
    }
    FILE* inputfile = fopen(filename, "r");
    if(inputfile == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open \"%s\"\n", filename);
        return 1;
    }
    while (preprocess_get_line(label, instruction, inputfile))
    {
        fprintf("%s: %s", label, instruction);
    }
    return 0;
}

int preprocess_get_line(char label[], char instruction[], FILE* fp)
{
    fgets(str,260, fp);
    while(character != EOF)
    {
        printf("ASCII hex: %2x '%c'\n", (int)character, character);
        character = fgets(inputfile);
    }
    fclose(inputfile); 
}
```

This is my code that I've written however I keep on receiving multiple errors in my code.
A specific error that I have in line 19
**label undeclared(first use in this function)**
my understanding is that I've already declared the function(on line 2.)
Another error in line 19
**each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in**
As for this error i'm not particularly sure as to what the problem is.

Comment: Please indent your code.

Comment: You should probably start with very simple programs first.

Comment: FYI, that second one is just an informational message from the compiler that it doesn't report an error for a missing variable again if it's already been reported once for that function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`label` and `instruction` are not defined on Line 19. You defined `inputfile`, but not the other two.